# One to many relationship in Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I want to create a relationship between `Users` and `Notifications` which I think is a one-to-many relationship.

I'm having trouble with this and not sure how I am going wrong. Here is the code for the two classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}

public class Notification
{
    public int NotificationID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following mapping on it:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
    .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(u => u.ApplicationUser)
    .WithMany(u => u.Notifications)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.NotificationID);
```

I have came across different errors while trying to fix this such as:

- Multiplicity is not valid
- Multiplicity constraint violated. The role _ of the relationship _ has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Edit:

The same exception (Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Notification_ApplicationUser_Target' of the relationship Notification_ApplicationUser' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.) is thrown when I try to add notifications for all users as I have it done in this method:

```
public void AddNotification(Notification n)
{
    var roleId = context.Roles.Where(m => m.Name == "User").Select(m => m.Id).SingleOrDefault();
    var users = context.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.All(r => r.RoleId == roleId)).ToList();
    try
    {
        foreach(var user in users)
        {
            user.Notifications.Add(n);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is coming from the string type of the foreign key. By default strings are nullable at the database level, but a required foreign key cannot be null. Specifying `HasRequired` only enforces that the relationship is required, not that the foreign key property must be not null. I think if you simply add `[Required]` to your foreign key property, that will correct the issue:

```
[Required]
public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
```

Obviously, you will need to do a migration to apply this change to your database.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I read into the exception wrong. The source of your problem is actually from adding the same notification to each user, as in literally the same notification. EF does object tracking, so after the entity instance referenced by `n` has been added once, it is being tracked by EF. Then, when you try to add it to another user, it thinks you're trying to do a many-to-many, basically, where that single `Notification` record will belong to multiple users.

Off the top of my head, I'm not sure what the best method is to fix this confusion in EF, but I have a couple of potential ideas:

1. You can try to detach the entity after adding it:

   ```
   user.Notifications.Add(n);
   context.Entry(n).State = EntityState.Detached;
   ```

   However, I'm not sure if that will allow it to be added at all. You'll have to test. If it doesn't create it, you can also try saving before detaching. I think that would work, but it's obviously pretty inefficient committing to the database each iteration.
2. The safest method would be to create a new instance for each, and simply map over the data from `n`:

   ```
   var notification = new Notification
   {
       Title = n.Title,
       Description = n.Description,
       Time = n.Time
   };
   user.Notifications.Add(notification);
   ```

   That will ensure that every notification you add is a totally separate tracked instance.

Comment: I applied this change and added the migration like you said but still the same error appears (Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Notification_ApplicationUser_Target' of the relationship 'Project.DAL.Notification_ApplicationUser' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1)

Comment: Chris you Savior. thanks for your time. I chose to create a new instance each time this makes the most sense to me and cleared up the problem for me completely and no more exceptions triggered with this method.

Comment: Also to clarify my approach this way, some notifications will be shared to all users and some of them will be individual ones. For example new content added will notify all the users and the other scenario is the user submits a high score and this notifies just the user on his/her own

Comment: If you're going to have any shared notifications, it's probably better to do an M2M. You can always just attach to a single user if that's required, but then you're covered either way.

Comment: For what it's worth, that's likely why this was an issue in the first place. You were basically trying to treat a one to many as a many to many, and that's why EF was confused. None of this extra code would be necessary if the relationship is many to many and you also wouldn't have a bunch of basically duplicate notification records.

Comment: I'll take your advice and implement it that way, doesn't make sense to fill my table with duplicates like you mentioned. cheers

Comment: That's what confused me originallly, I understand that a record inserted directly into notifications could be accessed by each user but how could I insert it for one specific user? if you have any examples to point me towards that would be appreciated.

Comment: You just add it as normal. Your collection will simply be a collection of one.

Comment: I have just one more question Chris, is there a way to retrieve all the notifications and include the notifications specific to a user? I now have a table in my database called UserNotifications and a table called Notifications. The general notifications go one way and the user specific one only contains notifications targeted for the user. This has me a little confused.

Comment: UserNotifications is your M2M join table; you won't utilize that one directly. To get notifications for a specific user, you can either access the user's `Notifications` collection, i.e. `user.Notifications` or you can can query notifications that have a relationship with that user: `db.Notifications.Where(m => m.Users.Any(u => u.Id == userId))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proper configuration of your relationship:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
                .HasRequired(u => u.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(u => u.Notifications)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.ApplicationUserID);
```

In `HasForeignKey` method you need to specify the FK of that relationship, not the PK of `Notification` entity.

### Update

The problem is you have an one to one relationship in your DB and you are trying to configure an one to many in your model. If this last one is what you really wants, then I suggest you to use [Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) to change your DB schema, otherwise you can configure your relationship this way:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
                .HasRequired(u => u.ApplicationUser)
                .WithOptional(u => u.Notification)
```

And change the navigation property in `ApplicationUser` entity:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
       public string FirstName { get; set; }

       public virtual Notification Notification { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, could you please check the question that I have updated

Comment: those tables already exist in your DB? Because the exception says is 1-1 relationship

Comment: that's the problem (I think). The real relationship is one to one and you are trying to configure an one to many

Comment: So the current relationship it expects is one to one and what I'm trying to force on the table is one to many? is there a way to fix this?

Comment: So if I update my model this way it will give me a one to many relationship? Like my original model has an ICollection which I believed stored the collection of notifications associated with the user?

Comment: If in your real world an user can have more than one notification then you need to change the DB schema, check the link I quoted and follow the steps to update your schema via EF, or you could try to do it manually

Comment: Yes i want a user to have more than one notification. I understand migrations, is my schema correct the way it is?

Comment: No, you need to change it using Migration or doing it manually

Comment: change it to what exactly is what I want to know? what way is it wrong now?